# Сколько придаточных в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, сказуемые

***Не помню, чего больше было больше во мне : стыда или ужаса.***

Answer (score 1):

Одно, осложнённое однородными членами с обобщающим словом.

Если обобщающее слово убрать, получится: Не помню, стыда или ужаса  было больше во мне.

Comment: А в этом предложении , выделенное сочетание чем является? Я не могу определить это - уточняющее обстоятельство или придаточное : Утром , КОГДА Я ПРОСНУЛСЯ , через окно я увидел , как большая серая птица села на ветку.

Comment: Придаточное времени, относится к сказуемому. Увидел когда? утром и когда? -когда я проснулся.

Answer (score 0):

3 предложения, в целом предложение сложное с различными видами связи. Между первым и вторым связь подчинительная, между вторым и третьим - бессоюзная. Грамматических основ три, правда, третья отсутствует, так как предложение третье неполное. Первое П - определённо-личное (односоставное), второе односоставное, безличное, третье - односоставное, безличное и, как и уже упоминалось, неполное.

Comment: А если так: "Не помню, чего больше, стыда или ужаса,  было  во мне". Тоже три предложения?

Answer (score 0):

Не помню, чего было больше во мне : стыда или ужаса.
В этой конструкции, состоящей из 2 простых предложений, есть главное "не помню" и придаточное изъяснительное, присоединённое союзным словом "чего", оно же является  и обобщающим словом(дополнением) перед двумя однородными дополнениями "стыда" и "ужаса". Грамматическая основа во втором предложении  - было больше (составное именное сказуемое). Таким образом, это СПП с одним придаточным предложением.